# WCF calls twice or more itself, but only if I keep a code line (I need it)

Tags: c#, wcf, loops, connection, iis-express

I have a weird problem. I've made a couple of working wcf. I've updated one of them and it seems all ok.

But, if I call a method with a get within the browser, I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. Debbuging it, I've found that the code is looping, calling itself twice or three times, when the call is only one.

The code is really similar to other, but there is something I can't understand.

Why does it loop?

This is the code of my method:

```
    public List<WrapImpianti> GetImpianto(string codret, string storeID, string hashedString, string outputType)
    {
        Utility.Logger("GetImpianto: start " + outputType);
        var md5 = new md5Manager();
        string key = "";
        IS_RETISTI retista = getRetista(codret);
        if (retista != null)
            key = retista.CHIAVEDES;
        List<WrapImpianti> r = new List<WrapImpianti>();
        //return r;
        if (md5.checkHashedInput(codret + storeID, hashedString, key))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new AccessData.Entities())
                {
                    var t = db.IS_IMPIANTI.Where(x => x.STOREID == storeID && x.IDRET == retista.ID).ToList();
                    r = t.Select(x => new WrapImpianti(x, key)).ToList();
                }
                return r;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new WebFaultException<string>(ex.Message, HttpStatusCode.Conflict);
            }
        }
        else
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("Hash non corretto", HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

If I comment the row "r = t.Select(x => new WrapImpianti(x, key)).ToList();", it works... or, at least, it returns an empty object (because I don't populate it) without looping.

Why? It only calls the init method of my class WrapImpianti...

this is the class

```
[DataContract]
    public class WrapImpianti
    {
        public WrapImpianti(){}
        private IS_IMPIANTI model;
        private string key;

        public WrapImpianti(IS_IMPIANTI model, string key)
        {
            this.model = model;
            this.key = key;
        }
        private string p_STOREID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string STOREID 
        { 
            get 
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_STOREID.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.STOREID.ToSafeString(); 
            }
            set { p_STOREID = value; }

        }
        private string p_CODICE { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CODICE
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_CODICE.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.CODICE.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_CODICE = value; }
        }
        private string p_CODRETE { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CODRETE
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_CODRETE.ToSafeString();
                else
                {
                    using (var db = new AccessData.Entities())
                    {
                        var pp = db.IS_RETISTI.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.model.IDRET);
                        if (pp != null)
                            return pp.CODICE;
                        else
                            return "";
                    }
                }
            }
            set { p_CODRETE = value; }
        }
        private string p_INDIRIZZO { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string INDIRIZZO
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_INDIRIZZO.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.INDIRIZZO.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_INDIRIZZO = value; }
        }
        private string p_CITTA { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CITTA
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_CITTA.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.CITTA.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_CITTA = value; }
        }
        private string p_STATO { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string STATO
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_STATO.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.STATO.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_STATO = value; }
        }
        private string p_COD_ESERCENTE { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string COD_ESERCENTE
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_COD_ESERCENTE.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.COD_ESERCENTE.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_COD_ESERCENTE = value; }
        }
        private string p_TERMINAL_ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TERMINAL_ID
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_TERMINAL_ID.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.TERMINAL_ID.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_TERMINAL_ID = value; }
        }
        private string p_COL { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string COL
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_COL.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.COL.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_COL = value; }
        }
        private string p_NOME { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string NOME
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_NOME.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.NOME.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_NOME = value; }
        }
        private string p_CAP { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CAP
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_CAP.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.CAP.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_CAP = value; }
        }
        private string p_TELUFF { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TELUFF
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_TELUFF.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.TELUFF.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_TELUFF = value; }
        }
        private string p_TELCELL { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string TELCELL
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_TELCELL.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.TELCELL.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_TELCELL = value; }
        }
        private string p_NOTE { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string NOTE
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_NOTE.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.NOTE.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_NOTE = value; }
        }
        private string p_PIVA { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PIVA
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_PIVA.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.PIVA.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_PIVA = value; }
        }
        private string p_CODICEFISCALE { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CODICEFISCALE
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_CODICEFISCALE.ToSafeString();
                else
                    return this.model.CODICEFISCALE.ToSafeString();
            }
            set { p_CODICEFISCALE = value; }
        }
        private string p_GESTORE { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string GESTORE
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_GESTORE.ToSafeString();
                else
                {
                    using (var db = new AccessData.Entities())
                    {
                        return db.IS_GESTORI.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.model.IDGES).CODICE.ToSafeString();
                    }
                }
            }
            set { p_GESTORE = value; }
        }
        private string p_PROPRIETARIO { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PROPRIETARIO
        {
            get
            {
                if (model == null)
                    return p_PROPRIETARIO.ToSafeString();
                else
                {
                    using (var db = new AccessData.Entities())
                    {
                        return db.IS_PROPRIETARI.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.model.IDPRP).CODICE.ToSafeString();
                    }
                }
            }
            set { p_PROPRIETARIO = value; }
        }
    }
```

Why, if I call my class init method, does it start looping? And then, why does it return ERR_CONNECTION_RESET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is interesting. The solutions was here:

```
    public string PROPRIETARIO
    {
        get
        {
            if (model == null)
                return p_PROPRIETARIO.ToSafeString();
            else
            {
                using (var db = new AccessData.Entities())
                {
                    return db.IS_PROPRIETARI.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == this.model.IDPRP).CODICE.ToSafeString();
                }
            }
        }
        set { p_PROPRIETARIO = value; }
```

in my customclass.. sometimes, the IDPRP is null and raises this error.

It is very interisting: I was expecting this type of error was more visible to the developer, instead of loop itself and get an anonymous error.

Hope it can be useful for someone. ;)